# Is the phpMyAdmin password the same as the MySQL server password?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, root

I have just installed MySQL and phpMyAdmin and when I logged in through phpMyAdmin using the root credentials it seemed to work and had the same password as MySQL server. However I also tried logging in with the account that was created during installation and that worked too.

So it must be that phpMyAdmin uses the usernames and passwords from the MySQL server instead of its own?

Sorry for the noob question, I did try searching this up before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is just a front end for MySQL - it uses these credentials.